# What is causing Unknown field error in EntityFieldQuery API?

Tags: database

I am attempting to use the entity-field-query API to see if any node of referee content type has custom field that equals x. I've looked at dozens of code examples and references. (Included below)

If it is relevant I am executing this code as a custom PHP action in Drupal rules.

My problem is when the code is executed I get the below error:

```
EntityFieldQueryException: Unknown field: field_referee_id‎ in EntityFieldQuery->addFieldCon
dition() (line 817 of /home/scienceorg/public_html/includes/entity.inc).
```

(The field does exist on the referee content type.)

**My code:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'referee')
    ->fieldCondition('field_referee_id‎', 'value', '1', '=');
    $result = $query->execute();
?>
```

**Further information:** If I remove the field condition line from the above code it works perfectly. So the problems seems to be around finding the field_referee_id.

Code references and examples

[EntityFieldQuery condition](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42087/entityfieldquery-condition)

https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708

**Alternative answer:** 
If you don't know what is causing the above problem I will accept alternative methods of achieving the same outcome as the correct answer.

Comment: You could try running this efq in à custom module, to make sure that the efq itself is working (might be a rules problem) Also, wat type is that field? If its annentityreference field you will need to replace value with target_id.

Comment: I might have to go the custom module route if I can't work it out. The field type is Integer and the widget is marked as a text field. Is the column still "value" for integers?

Answer (score 0):

The code above seems right only problem here might be the machine name of the field is not same as the one given in 
->fieldCondition('field_referee_id‎', 'value', '1', '=');
or the field might be multivalued field, for multivalued field in place of '=' 'IN' should be used.

Comment: I've switched it to IN and still the same PHP error. I've copied the machine name directly from the content type fields page so that has to be right.

Do you know of any other methods for seeing if any nodes of a certain content have have a custom field value of x?

Comment: It works as it is written. You can query the field table directly for checking the value of the field and can get entity id out of that table having the referee_id and check for the bundle within the same query.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: $query = db_select('field_data_field_referee_id'); $query->condition('field_referee_id_value', 1); $query->condition('bundle', 'referee'); $query->fields('field_data_field_referee_id', array('entity_id')); This query might help you.

Comment: When I do a var_dump($result) that code isn't showing me anything on the referee content types. Would you be able to explain what $query->fields('field_data_field_referee_id', array('entity_id'));  is doing differently to ->fieldCondition('field_referee_id‎', 'value', '1', '=');? (It doesn't look like it's comparing it with the value 1)